# Long running script stops sending output to file

Tags: shell-script, rhel, background-process, nohup

I have a script that I'm using to capture some status of the server at 10 second intervals.

The script is as follows:

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
    /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl fullstatus
    sleep 10
done
```

And I am running the script using:

```
nohup /path/to/scriptname.sh | gzip > logfile.log.gz &
```

It will run in the background and keep running if I disconnect from ssh.  However, after about 3-4 hours the output stops getting transferred to the logfile.  The script is still running and shows up if I run ps -elf | grep scriptname, but the logfile does not update.  Why does the output stop sending?  Is this possibly a problem with the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gzip` file format has an 8-byte footer containing a CRC-32 checksum and uncompressed length of the data. The [DEFLATE file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) is block-oriented. The `gzip` program in the pipeline is almost certainly buffering up input to use in the next output block. The 8-byte footer won't be written until after the long-running shell script exits, and `gzip`'s stdin closes. I think you'll have to wait for a long while to see if DEFLATE blocks aren't periodically written to the log file.